# Hash check for URL constantly firing function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following functions. When the a-link is clicked, it changes the url and adds a hash to it. I then run a check to see if there is a hash. I get the name after the text and load the relevant content.

My problem is that the changePage function fires constantly. Even if I add a flag check. See below -

```js
var changeCheck = true;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.nav-link').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault( );
        var pageRef = $(this).attr('href');

        window.history.pushState('changeUrl', 'Title', '/DigiOutsourceTask/#' + pageRef);
        changeCheck = true;

        changePage(pageRef)
        
    });

    if(window.location.hash && changeCheck === true){
        console.log('hash');
        changePage(window.location.hash.slice(1));
    }
            
});


function changePage(href){

    $( "#home-body" ).load(href, function(){
        console.log('changed');
    });
    changeCheck = false;
    console.log(href,'click');
}
```

```html
<div id="home-body"></div>
                <ul class="main-menu-list">
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link about" href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean by “it fires constantly”?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the if statement along with everything inside of it since it is redundant to the functioning of the script.

On line 11 of the snippet the function call is missing a semi-colon to end the line.